# mongodb embedded objects search

Tags: regex, mongodb

I got these documents:

- users -> id, name, friendList (_id, name), createdOn

I have to search for a friend in the friend list so what I got is:

```
$users->find(array('_id' => $userId, 'friendList.name' => new MongoRegex('/' . strtolower($keyword) . '/'), array('friendList.name')));
```

The problem is that it will return all friendlist names, how can I just obtain the information about the "friend" I am trying to search?

Thanks for help already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in mongo, you can search for a particular element, but mongo will always return the whole array, so you have to extract the element yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Please reference this documentation page.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements

There are ways to retrieve subsets of arrays, though I'm not sure this will help you.